# Последний бой замыканию

Tags: javascript

```js
function makeCounter() {
  var currentCount = 1;

  return function() { // (**)
    return currentCount++;
  };
}

var counter = makeCounter();

console.log(counter()); // 1
console.log(counter()); // 2
console.log(counter()); // 3
```

1. При создании функции `makeCounter` она получает скрытое свойство `[[scope]]`.
2. При вызову функции создается лексическое окружение **LP**.
3. В **LP** заносится `var currentCount = 1;`.
4. В переменную `counter` возвращается анонимная функция.
5. Переменная `counter` стала функцией.
6. Вызываем `counter()`, где интерпретатор не знает `currentCount` и идет через скрытое свойство `[[scope]]` в функцию где была создана функция и возвращает **LP** где `currentCount 1`.
7. `currentCount++`  она в постпрефиксной форме значит увеличит на **1**, но вернет старое значение.
8. Главное надо запомнить, что `[[scope]]` идет в **LP** и изменяет **LP**.
9. Каждый раз когда мы вызываем функцию  `makeCounter()`, создается свой **LP**.
10. Правильно я понял замыкания и скрытое свойство `[[scope]]`?

Comment: Правильно. Молодец.

Comment: у функций нет свойства [[scope]]

Comment: @Grundy  а что есть ?

Comment: @ Igor тут один гражданин написал, что у функций нет скрытого свойства [[scope]] верно ?